# How to make in-app purchase for Android HTML5 based?

Tags: android, html, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, billing

I want to make my Android/HTML5 application be able to make in-app purchase, but i cant find any information on how to archive this. Some one has an idea how to get it done? any tutorial, walk-trough, examples will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript injection, where javascript from your webview can trigger android SDK methods

http://lexandera.com/2009/01/injecting-javascript-into-a-webview/